# History, origin & usage of term ‘showroom’ instead of shop / store / storefront?

Tags: etymology, history, phrase-origin

What is the history, origin & usage of the term ‘showroom’ instead of shop / store / storefront?

How / where did it come about?
Who came up with it?

While the term appears in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/showroom), there is no etymology. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Showroom) is similarly silent on the origin, though [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/showroom) dates the verb form back to 2011.

Comment: I understand a showroom to be a place where you go to look at items for sale which are too large to carry away with you, to decide which kind you want and possibly place an order for one like it. For instance washing machines, gas fires, new cars.

Comment: Yes. I’d like to know how & when the usage of the word started.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/showroom) says the first known usage was 1616, but not where.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I wonder what was being SHOWN Off first? Especially in 1616. Jewellry? Horse Carriages?

Comment: Perhaps the first use of "showroom" was for a "theatre".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED confirms the *Merriam Webster* assertion of 1616. It gives in all three senses of the word but I believe the one you are looking for is sense 1. **But clearly its importance takes off with the arrival of a consumerist society in the late-eighteenth, and early-nineteenth centuries.**

> 1. A room used to display goods for sale, (now) esp. large items such as vehicles, appliances, or furniture. Also figurative.
>
> 1616   R. Cocks Diary 2 Jan. (1883) I. 95   To keepe the shopp or shew
>   rowme.
>
> 1617   R. Cocks Diary 23 July 283   We delivered divers sortes
>   merchandiz to Jno. Japon to sell in the shopp or shew roome over the
>   way.
>
> 1781   S. Neville Diary 30 Oct. (1950) xii. 280   The finished goods
>   are placed in a long shew room for the inspection of strangers.
>
> 1829   T. Carlyle Voltaire in Crit. & Misc. Ess. (1840) II. 163
>   Voltaire's knowledge is not a mere show-room of curiosities, but truly
>   a museum for purposes of teaching.
>
> 1839   Dickens Nicholas Nickleby x. 93   Madame Mantalini's show-rooms
>   were on the first floor.
>
> 1879   F. W. Robinson Coward Conscience II. xxi. 160   From the busy
>   workshops into the great show-room.
>
> 1936   Motorboating Jan. 78/2   The importance to a customer of seeing
>   his prospective purchase in the water and not only on the showroom
>   floor.
>
> 1959   News Chron. 28 Nov. 6/8   At many hi-fi showrooms you can hear
>   the relative performances of different speakers.
>
> 2007   Independent 10 Feb. (Save & Spend section) 9/1   One of the
>   first Audi R8 supercars, coming to a showroom near you.

The other two senses given are:

> 2. A room in which a show (in various senses) takes place. Now esp.: a room in a hotel, nightclub, etc., in which entertainment is performed.
> 3. Any of the rooms in a mansion, stately home, or the like which are regularly open to the public for viewing. Usually in plural.